# Facebook SDK cURL and SSL Error

Tags: php, facebook

I try to use facebook API for my website.
But I get some error like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 1: Protocol https not supported
>   or disabled in libcurl thrown in
>   /home/batav1/public_html/permaisuri/include/fbsdk/src/base_facebook.php
>   on line 887

I checked curl configuration bu typing phpinfo() and here is the result

```
cURL support enabled
cURL Information libcurl/7.21.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

What should I do?
Here is my code :

```
<?php
require 'include/fbsdk/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '33025497038xxxx',
  'secret' => '87be6ab5175a9be7c7d48be74dd5xxxx',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your php setup doesnt seem to support the `https` wrapper

To alow https wraper :- the `php_openssl` extension must exist and enabled - `allow_url_include` must be set to on

in the php.ini file you add this lines if not exists:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll

allow_url_include = On
```

Comment: He's using curl, so allow_url_include is not neccessary.

Comment: And you're using a windows dll, while according to the error and its /home/.. path I'm guessing he is on linux/unix variant...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the curl extension does not have ssl support compiled in. You should recompile PHP with the options --with-curl and --with-openssl.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked my command, and seems like --with-curl have executed already. Should --with-openssl execute too?